# grep starting with slash for command df -h

Tags: kubernetes, grep

I want to run the command df -h on my pod kubernetes and extract just one line with grep but is not working:

```
$ df -h 

Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                 249.9G     39.8G    210.0G  16% 
tmpfs                    15.6G         0     15.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    15.6G    132.0M     15.5G   1% /etc/resolv.conf
tmpfs                    15.6G    132.0M     15.5G   1% /etc/hostname
/dev/vdf                 10.0G      1.8G      8.2G  18% /application
/dev/vda1                50.0G     39.4G     10.6G  79% /etc/application
/dev/vda1                50.0G     39.4G     10.6G  79% /etc/test/application
/dev/vda1                50.0G     39.4G     10.6G  79% /dev/termination-log
```

**output expect:**

```
/dev/vdf                 10.0G      1.8G      8.2G  18% /application
```

**I'm trying to run this command:**

```
$ for i in `df -h`; do echo $i | grep '^\/application'; done
/dev/vdf                 10.0G      1.8G      8.2G  18% /application
/dev/vda1                50.0G     39.4G     10.6G  79% /etc/application
/dev/vda1                50.0G     39.4G     10.6G  79% /etc/test/application
```

I know you will say " **why you don't grep for /dev/vdf ?** , the answer is that the mounted partition **/application**  will have other pvc name bounded like "/dev/vdb"

Answer (score 1):

This seems really simple:

```
df -h | grep " /application"
```

If I understand correctly, you want to check the `df -h` output and get the one referring to `/application`, but you want to avoid getting `/etc/application` too.
Well, adding the space in front of `/application` solves this.

Comment: yes, i figured out after i posted here, thank you